# Retrive id and delete query using button in jsp

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, html-table

Friends i have a jsp page which retrieves data from sql table and displays them in form of table. I will also display another column consisting of a button to delete that row/entry from the sql table.
Following is the code for my jsp page:

```
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
            Connection  conn=null;  
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","pass");
            %>
    <body>
    <center>
        <h1>USERS TABLE</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        <%
            Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
            String s = "SELECT * FROM login";
            ResultSet r = stm.executeQuery(s);
            while ( r.next() )
             { 
                 out.print("<tr>");
                 out.print("<td>" +  r.getString ("userid") + "</td>" ); 
                 out.print("<td>" +  r.getString ("username") + "</td>");
                 out.print("<td>" +  "<input type=button value='Delete'/>"+ "</td>");
                 out.print("</tr>");
             }
         %>     
        </table>
    </center>
    </body>
```

Now i want my delete button to extract the userid and pass a query to delete the selected user from the database. I am just confused about how to achieve this userid extraction and process the query.

Comment: Why not an url instead of a button?

Comment: @RobertRozas: Actions that manipulate data should always be made using POST requests (although the OP does not seem to be doing that here either) – otherwise, if the request was made via GET (and requires no further [server-side] confirmation) bots, link prefetching etc. could already trigger the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
out.print("<td>"+"<input type='button' value='Delete' id='"+r.getString("userid")+"'/>"+</td>");
```

And check for the user id to delete, just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(":button").click(function(){
    alert("Deleting user id: "+this.id);
});

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fvAMD/

Comment: Could you tell me how to access the id for every delete button so i can use it on my servlet to use delete sql query?

Comment: With this.id you can retrieve the userid associated to the button

Comment: How? That's what i was asking. I read somewhere that id attribute cannot be accessed by servlet.

Comment: You can call your servlet via ajax: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/calling-servlets-using-ajax.html#fbid=9_L1psKIBt1

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to do like this

1}First create a servlet(say Display.java) and store the database contents in a response attribute.Send the response attribute to a jsp (say home.jsp)

2}In the jsp file retrieve the response attribute and and make a delete button and when OnClick is called run a script which direct it to a servlet(say deleteData1.java) which perform the deletion operation.

i am attaching the corresponding codes below.

(Display.java)
It will store the database contents in an arrayList object. further that arrayList object will be stored in response attribute and send to jsp(home.jsp).

```
public Display() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection conn = null;

    Statement st;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","pass");

        ArrayList al=null;
        ArrayList userList =new ArrayList();
        String query = "select userid,username from login";

        st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);


        while(rs.next())
        {
            al  = new ArrayList();
            al.add(rs.getInt(1));
            al.add(rs.getString(2));
            userList.add(al);
        }

        request.setAttribute("userList",userList);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

(home.jsp)

It will retrieve the response attribute sent from Display.java. A script is called when the delete button is clicked which will forward it to a servlet which will perform the deletion operation corresponding to that id.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*;" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script language ="javascript">

function deleteData(id){
    window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/First/deleteData1?id="+id;  
}


</script>

</head>
<body>
<br>
<table align="center">
</table>
<br>

<table border='1' width='300' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><td colspan=3 align="center"></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>UserId</td><td>userName</td>
</tr>                       

<%

List Li = new ArrayList();
Iterator  lr;

if(request.getAttribute("userList")!=null && request.getAttribute("userList")!="")
{
    List userList =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("userList");
    Iterator itr = userList.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {

        Li = (ArrayList)itr.next();
        lr = Li.iterator();
        Integer id = (Integer)lr.next();
        %>
        <tr>
        <td><%=id%></td>
        <%  
        while(lr.hasNext())
        {

            %>
            <td> <%=lr.next()%></td>

            <%

        }
        %>
        <td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteData(<%=id%>);"></td>
        </tr>
        <%
    }
}
%>

}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally when the delete button will be clicked then the script will run which will direct it to servlet(deleteData1.java) which will perform the delete operation

(deleteData1.java)

```
@WebServlet("/deleteData1")
public class deleteData1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public deleteData1() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Connection conn = null;
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=Tpg@1234");
        String query = "delete from login where id="+id;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        if(i>0){
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/First/Display");
        }
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use Hyperlink instead of button

```
<td>
   <a href="Edit?userd=<%=rs.getString(1) %>"> Activate </a>
<td>
```

Then you should have to ceate Edit servlet or jsp page for writing your Query